# jQuery function based on area of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to feed a cat with burgers. If you grab a burger and bring it to the cat's mouth, the burger should disappear.

Currently it looks like that:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".burger").draggable();
});

$(".burger").on("click touchend", function() {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.burger {
  cursor: grab;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Manul_kitten.jpg">

<div class="burger"></div>
<div class="burger"></div>
<div class="burger"></div>
```

How can I let it work that the burger only disappears close to the cat's mouth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create hidden element above the image and set droppable.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".burger").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
     ui.draggable.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.burger {
  cursor: grab;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative
}

.droppable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 125px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid yellow; /*remove to hide*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="droppable"></div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Manul_kitten.jpg">
</div>


<div class="burger"></div>
<div class="burger"></div>
<div class="burger"></div>
```